# Sending mail before changing header location

Tags: php

From php.net:

```
<html>
<?php
/* This will give an error. Note the output
 * above, which is before the header() call */
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
?>
```

Is it ok to read cookies and use mail() before changing header location?

Comment: but it is not ok to have `<html>` tag printed before sending header. Because headers always go first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`header()` will give errors, if something before it is printed on screen. If your cookie reading won't echo/print something out, then it should be ok. Same applies to `mail()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is perfectly OK to read cookie and use mail() before header location for redirecting.